# Sapper: point middleware's "ignore" dirs to "_error.svelte"

Tags: svelte, sapper

I've set sapper to ignore some dirs by routes, like this:

```
polka()
    .use(
        sapper.middleware({
            // Exclude components from routing
            ignore: ['/admin', '/components'],
    )
    .listen(PORT);
```

And now, navigating browser in http://localhost:3000/admin and http://localhost:3000/components it prints single:

`Not Found`

Can I point those paths to regular `/routes/_error.svelte` with 404 error somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `ignore` literally causes Sapper to ignore the request.  Internally it just calls `next()` when it sees one of these routes.  You can get the behaviour you want by changing the route to a non-existent one:

```
function handle_ignored(req, res, next) {
    if (['/admin', '/components'].some(path => req.path.startsWith(path))) {
        req.path = '/_error'; // ... or any other non-existent path
    }
    next();
}

polka()
    .use(
        handle_ignored,
        sapper.middleware()
    )
    .listen(PORT, err => {
        if (err) console.log('error', err);
    });
```

Comment: Big thx, man, btw, I love _, but suddenly we a on JS field now) so, handleIgnored